# Easy way to iterate over a vector of pair of pair

Tags: c++, auto

Is there an easy way to iterate over a vector of pair of pair using `auto`?

I have a `vector<pair<pair<int,int>, int>> vec` and want to iterate something like.

```
for(auto [x, y,z] : vec)
```

but I am getting an error. Is there an easy way to do so?

```
for(auto [[x,y],z] : vec)
```

also gives an error.

Comment: For easier googling in future: this construct is called [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like shown below.

```cpp
for (auto& it: vec) {
  auto[x, y, z] = tie(it.first.first, it.first.second, it.second);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of tie.

Comment: I would not use name `it` for non iterator types (as pair (or pair)).

Comment: This is just an example. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Which standard does this require?

Comment: @Miguel: C++17 for structured binding (`auto [x, y, z] = ..`) part.

Answer (score 3):

You could write:

```
for (auto & [p, z] : vec) 
{
  auto & [x, y] = p;
  // ... use x, y, z
}
```